# Cannot change footer text?

Tags: widgets, footer

I've been trying to edit a footer.php file for the Wordpress eCommerce theme called SornaCommerce. There is a text that says "Proudly powered by WordPress | Theme: SornaCommerce by eDataStyle.". Instead of that I want to add some links and widgets.

The footer.php text says the following

```
</div>
```

```
    <?php
/**
* Hook - sornacommerce_site_footer_block.
*
* @hooked sornacommerce_site_footer_block - 10
*/
do_action('sornacommerce_site_footer_block');
?>
```

That's the part I think makes the footer (when I remove it the footer is removed). How can I insert my own links and stuff? Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1):

The original theme url here ( https://wordpress.org/themes/sornacommerce/ )

The theme working by using WordPress hooks

You can update this file: `sornacommerce\inc\theme-hooks.php` on line 438 to 497

Otherwise remove the function on the hook like bellow:

```
remove_action( 'sornacommerce_site_footer_block', 'sornacommerce_site_footer_block' );
```

Then add new function to the same hook like bellow:

```
function wpse291732_footer() {
// your function
 }
add_action("sornacommerce_site_footer_block", "wpse291732_footer");
```

Hope that will be okay !

Answer (score 0):

That's an action you can hook into, see also [the Action reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

To add your own code that gets executed when this action is called, use [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/), like so:

```
function wpse291732_footer() {
print '<a href="http://example.com/">Go to example.com!</a>';
}
add_action("sornacommerce_site_footer_block", "wpse291732_footer");
```

add_action also supports passing it a priority as the third parameter (default: 10) that determines the order of execution (lower priority gets executed first).